# How to export master secret from browser SSL/TLS session?

Tags: browser, ssl, encryption

I'd like to open a browser in Windows, go to an HTTPS site, and perform a sequence of actions while capturing packets with Wireshark.  Then I want to use the encrypted packet capture to view the decrypted HTTP traffic.  I know of many ways to do this (listed below) if you forego the browser, have access to the server, or add a MITM, but none of these work when you're restricted to the scenario above.  Here are my typical approaches:

Server:  For sites where I have the server private key, use Wireshark's built-in SSL decryption.

MITM:  An SSL proxy (e.g., Burp suite) will allow viewing of decrypted traffic, but this requires using a different certificate and key pair than what is used by the server.

Browser:  openssl's s_client can connect, make requests, and export the master secret, but this does not display the associated web pages or run javascript to compute subsequent request parameters.

Is there a way to export the master secret from a "normal" browser so that I can use it to later decrypt a packet capture of the browser session?

For example, is SSL/TLS state stored on disk when a browser is closed?  If so, how would I access it?  Is it accessible in memory while the browser is running (and if so how would I find it)?

Or, is all SSL state data stored by the OS (Windows) and not accessible directly?

Alternatively, is there a way to force a browser to use a particular master secret (and any other associated SSL state data like session ID, etc.) for a particular HTTPS connection?  If so, I could set up the SSL session using s_client, and then transfer the key data to the browser and open a new connection in the same session.  This would accomplish the same goal through different means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For browsers that use the NSS library (e.g. Firefox) you can set the `SSLKEYLOGFILE` [environment variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_reference/NSS_environment_variables), which will cause NSS to save the necessary secrets. You can then directly use that file with Wireshark. There's more information to be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_Key_Log_Format).