# How does Windows implement TLS/SSL protocol in its programs such as IE,Powershell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, ssl, dll, dll-injection

I'm trying to decrypt TLS/SSL flow with Wireshark.

I believe that there are two ways to decrypt TLS/SSL flow using Wireshark

The one is providing Wireshark with private key of server's certificate.

The other is providing (pre)master-secret logfile.  -> (This is my plan)

I know that chrome and firefox have the way that extracted master secret log using SSLKEYLOGFILE variables.-
[How to export master secret from browser SSL/TLS session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013287/how-to-export-master-secret-from-browser-ssl-tls-session)

But as you know, IE does not provide SSLKEYLOGFILE function

I hope to extract pre-master-secret logfile from IE or Powershell

=========================================================================

## What I've tried so far

I'm working in Windows 7 32bit machine

I attached IE to Immunity Debugger to analyze which function generates pre-master secret.

There are many functions which is likely to generate pre-master-secret in schannel.dll and ncrypt.dll

for example ncrypt.dll has SslGenerateMasterKey,Tls1ComputeMasterKey.....

But those functions are not breakpointed when I execute TLS/SSL Program

And I tried almost every function in DLLs which were loaded to IE, but i couldn't find it.

=========================================================================

## My Question

1. Which function does generate (pre)master-key in IE or Powershell?
2. (If the function are not revealed in public) Do you have any tips for reverse engineering in this situation?

Comment: You can look at the certificates known to IE using Tools > Internet Options > Content > Certificates.  You can also import/export certificates from this dialog.  You can also view/configure trust and certificates from the "Certificates" MMC snap-in: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771157.aspx

Comment: Digging up this old threat to check whether you've found a solution. AFAIK only Chrome and FF use the `SSLKEYLOGFILE` variable to log premaster-secrets. I'm also looking for something similar that works for IE so that I can decrypt packets in Wireshark from sites browsed to in IE