# DTLS-SRTP server for testing, SRTP Master Key?

Tags: openssl, webrtc, dtls, ortc

I am trying to create a client which can accept a connection from a webrtc client. The part I am having difficulty with is the DTLS-SRTP portion, I would like to get the raw RTP stream. Currently I am using an openssl s_server with dtls and -use_srtp. I am able to get the SRTP stream, however I cannot decrypt it without the Master Key (can't find a way for openssl to dump the key..). If I am able to get the Master Key exchanged within the dtls, I can decrypt the packets.

Anyone try to do something similar?

Thanks

Comment: [How do I extract the pre-master secret using an OpenSSL-based client?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36240279/608639), [Premaster secret and master key in OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13324785/608639), [How to export master secret from browser SSL/TLS session?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15013287/608639), and a few others on the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract the pre-master secret using an OpenSSL-based client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240279/how-do-i-extract-the-pre-master-secret-using-an-openssl-based-client)